# how to read td contents from the html page and convert to Dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, web-scraping

The bellow is my content

```
`'<tablecellspacing="0"cellpadding="4"rules="all"id="DataGrid1"style="background-color:White;border-color:#3366CC;border-width:1px;border-style:None;height:65px;width:268px;border-collapse:collapse;"><trstyle="color:#CCCCFF;background-color:#003399;font-weight:bold;"><td>State</td><td>Centre</td><td>Variety</td><td>Unit</td><td>03/01/2020</td><td>10/01/2020</td><td>17/01/2020</td><td>24/01/2020</td><td>31/01/2020</td><td>07/02/2020</td><td>14/02/2020</td><td>21/02/2020</td><td>28/02/2020</td><td>06/03/2020</td><td>13/03/2020</td><td>20/03/2020</td><td>27/03/2020</td><td>03/04/2020</td><td>10/04/2020</td><td>17/04/2020</td></tr><trstyle="color:#003399;background-color:White;white-space:nowrap;"><tdstyle="background-color:#3CFFCE;font-weight:bold;">Apple</td><td></td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr><trstyle="color:#003399;background-color:White;white-space:nowrap;"><td>AndhraPradesh</td><td>Chittoor</td><td>Deliciousmediumsize</td><td>Kg.</td><td>130.00</td><td>130.00</td><td>140.00</td><td>140.00</td><td>140.00</td><td>140.00</td><td>150.00</td><td>150.00</td><td>140.00</td><td>150.00</td><td>150.00</td><td>150.00</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr><trstyle="color:#003399;background-color:White;white-space:nowrap;"><td>AndhraPradesh</td><td>Guntur</td><td>Deliciousmediumsize</td><td>Kg.</td><td>100.00</td><td>100.00</td><td>100.00</td><td>110.00</td><td>110.00</td><td>120.00</td><td>120.00</td><td>120.00</td><td>120.00</td><td>120.00</td><td>120.00</td><td>120.00</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr><trstyle="color:#003399;background-color:White;white-space:nowrap;"><td>AndhraPradesh</td><td>Kurnool</td><td>Deliciousmediumsize</td><td>Kg.</td><td>110.00</td><td>110.00</td><td>120.00</td><td>120.00</td><td>120.00</td><td>120.00</td><td>120.00</td><td>120.00</td><td>120.00</td><td>120.00</td><td>120.00</td><td>120.00</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr></table>`'
```

when i print td.text it gives elements but i am not sure how to put that it into a Pandas Dataframe

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(Content, 'lxml')
TD = soup.findAll('td')

for td in TD:
    print(td.text)

State
Centre
Variety
Unit
03/01/2020
10/01/2020
17/01/2020

AndhraPradesh
Chittoor
Deliciousmediumsize
Kg.
130.00
130.00
130.00
 
AndhraPradesh
Guntur
Deliciousmediumsize
Kg.
100.00
100.00
100.00
 
AndhraPradesh
Kurnool
Deliciousmediumsize
Kg.
110.00
110.00
120.00
```

My expected outcome(sample)

```
Date            state        center         variety            Unit  value
03/01/2020  AndhraPradesh   Chittoor       Deliciousmediumsize  kg    130
10/01/2020  AndhraPradesh   Guntur         Deliciousmediumsize  kg    100
17/01/2020  AndhraPradesh   Kurnool        Deliciousmediumsize  kg    110
```

Can anyone help me on this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
In [149]: Content = Content.replace( 'trstyle' , 'tr style')

In [.  ]: soup = BeautifulSoup(Content, 'lxml')
     ...: TR = soup.findAll('tr')

In [151]: rownum = 0

In [152]: cols, data = [] , []
     ...: for tr in TR:
     ...:     if rownum == 0:
     ...:         for td in tr.findAll('td'):
     ...:             if td.text: cols.append(td.text)
     ...:
     ...:     else:
     ...:         row_data = []
     ...:         for td in tr.findAll('td'):
     ...:             if td.text:
     ...:                 row_data.append(td.text)
     ...:
     ...:         if row_data :data.append(row_data)
     ...:     rownum+=1
     ...:     print('row complete' )
     ...:
row complete
row complete
row complete
row complete
row complete

In [153]: data = data[1:] # because this was some null row with no data



In [154]: df = pd.DataFrame( data = data , columns = cols )

In [155]: id_vars = ['State', 'Centre' , 'Variety' , 'Unit']

In [156]: value_vars = list(set(df.columns ) - set( id_vars) )

In [157]: pd.melt(df, id_vars = id_vars , value_vars = value_vars, var_name = 'Date' )
Out[157]:
            State    Centre              Variety Unit        Date   value
0   AndhraPradesh  Chittoor  Deliciousmediumsize  Kg.  28/02/2020  140.00
1   AndhraPradesh    Guntur  Deliciousmediumsize  Kg.  28/02/2020  120.00
2   AndhraPradesh   Kurnool  Deliciousmediumsize  Kg.  28/02/2020  120.00
3   AndhraPradesh  Chittoor  Deliciousmediumsize  Kg.  10/01/2020  130.00
4   AndhraPradesh    Guntur  Deliciousmediumsize  Kg.  10/01/2020  100.00
5   AndhraPradesh   Kurnool  Deliciousmediumsize  Kg.  10/01/2020  110.00
```